# Should I use a localhost linked server or the HOST_NAME() function to avoid hard-coding this SQL Server hostname?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linked-server

I inherited a legacy system that has two SQL Server instances on the same server. Occasionally, some user action causes some records to be "synchronized" across the instances. The system uses a "linked server" so a sproc on the main instance can query the other instance. The `sys.servers` table has these records:

```
| server_id | name        | 
=========================== 
| 0         | sql08\main  |
| 1         | sql08\other |
```

The website that invokes the sproc stores the linked server name in a configuration file. I guess they expected it to change at some point, but it never has. It's always on the same host as the main instance.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="LinkedServer" value="sql08\other" />
</appSettings>
```

And that is passed to the sproc to generate a dynamic SQL statement. I'll skip the ADO.NET command/parameter stuff, it's all normal. The sproc does something like this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @LinkedServer + '].db.schema.table WHERE ...'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

I used web.config transforms to support pointing the Debug configuration to a test environment and the Release configuration to production. **But, I also need it to function on *any* developer workstation, which implies using `localhost`, not the actual hostname.**

### Option A: Add a Special Linked Server

I can require a special linked server using `localhost` instead of the hostname. I don't like that it's different than the test/production environments and will require custom setup. **Are there any "gotchas" here?** I couldn't find any guidance one way or the other.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'localhost\other', @srvproduct = 'SQL Server'
```

### Option B: Drop the Setting

Or, given that the linked server is *always* on the same host, I could use the `host_name()` function in the sproc, removing the need for configuration at all. **Is there anything to watch out for if I use this option**, besides the chance that the linked server moves?

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM [' + HOST_NAME() + '\other].db.schema.table WHERE ...'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a `SYNONYM` in your server and in production. This way you can have different linked servers and the rest of the system is unaware.

In development:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.linkedtable FOR [LOCALHOST\other].db.schema.table;
```

In production:

```
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.linkedtable FOR [SQL08\other].db.schema.table;
```

If you have a large number of these, create an additional linked server in both locations that has the same name.

If you have a script that runs on every single server you set up, then you can generate the synonym dynamically, e.g.:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'CREATE SYNONYM dbo.linkedtable FOR ['
  + HOST_NAME() + '\other].db.schema.table;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, wasn't aware of SYNONYM. But, given that SQL statement, I'd still need *one* per environment/system. Can I mix `HOST_NAME()` into that statement to generate a single, re-usable SYNONYM creation script?

Comment: Not sure I understand what the barrier is to defining one synonym per system. Is that harder than defining one synonym per system that sucks in `HOST_NAME()` (which is not possible, by the way)?

Comment: I'm not concerned about creating a synonym per system, I am concerned about *how* I do it. I will not manually run a custom script per system. I want to commit to source control a single setup script for *any* system. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, `one per environment/system` is completely different from `one synonym that gets created in a consistent way on ALL environments/systems`. Anyway I've updated my answer with a suggestion.